# How to distinguish the lock in ldap, whether it is locked manually by some admin user or is it due to incorrect password attempts?

Tags: ldap, openldap, spring-ldap, ldap-query

I have a requirement that user account will be locked if user tries with multiple incorrect password and alternatively admin can also lock the account, for incorrect pwd attempts I can use the attribute "pwdAccountLockedTime" but is there any recommendation for the admin lock?

Comment: No, there is only the one attribute, used on both occasions. I guess as a heuristic you could look at the number of `pwdFailureTime` entries, and if it is less than `pwdMaxFailures` in the policy entry you can assume an admin did the lock, but this doesn't catch all cases.

Comment: Is there any way to check the value of pwdFailureTime using ldap admin application. I am able to see other details like displayName, uid, modifiername but not the values like pwdFailureTime, pwdAccountLockedTime

Comment: You need to specify `+` as the attributes to display, to include the operational attributes such as this one.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, depending on your schema and password Policy, and as used within the popular  [slapo-ppolicy](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-ppolicy&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=OpenLDAP%202.3-Release) - Password Policy overlay and as defined in the "[Draft-behera-ldap-password-policy](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-behera-ldap-password-policy-11.txt)"

```
pwdAccountLockedTime

   This attribute contains the time that the user's  account  was  locked.
   If  the  account has been locked, the password may no longer be used to
   authenticate the user to the directory.  If pwdAccountLockedTime is set
   to  000001010000Z,  the  user's account has been permanently locked and
   may only be unlocked by an administrator.
```